# Java - Copy target of symlink to another dest

Tags: java, file, symlink

I've been making pictures on my world-trip the last five months and finally sorted all of them. Though I saved symlinks of the original pics and put them all together in one seperate folder (the symlinks). I've been looking for different methods to access the targets of the symlinks (the real pictures) and copy them to another directory for further processing. Now since there is clearly no software supporting symlinks, I was thinking why not to write a small script for myself copying the targets.

I've been searching all day now for different methods, e.g. using Files, FileUtils, file.getCanonical/Absolute Path, but none of them work. 
The Class Files simply ignores the symlink-targets. Same does FileUtils. file.getCanonical/AbsolutePath() also donsn't see the target path. When I compare the results of both methods, they are the same! No difference!

Do you know a way I could access the target path of the symlinks? Haven't found a way yet. In software or programming. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about Unix-style symbolic links created through `symlink`(2) at the API level or the `ln -s` command.

If you have file A being a symbolic link to a file B, and you want to access the contents of that file B, simply open the file A and process it as you normally would.  You will be processing the contents of file B.  The fact that file A is a symbolic link to the file B will be transparent to your program.

Comment: Alright. I'm working on windows. So what you are saying simply means, open file A, in e.g. a buffered reader, and save it like I'd normally do? Good to know :-)
EDIT: Cuz if I simply used Files.copy(), I'd copy the symlink A. Thats why I'd open the file in a bufferedReader and save it afterwards.